Questions around Entra External ID - should we have one external ID tenant per customer or application?
What is the recommendation from security and scalability perspective for the below queries?

Multiple applications ( app1, app2 ... app n) deployed in one external ID tenant for multiple customer identities

OR

One External ID tenant per application so that customer identities are not part of the same tenant ?

Design consideration queries.

It depends on your requirements.
How many users are in each app? How many apps? How many users in total?
For one tenant, you can use groups to ensure this user can use this app.
Also, users can share a group of apps if required with one login.
Management is simplified.
Billing is more complex.
However, for many apps. with many users you might hit the tenant limit.
Multiple tenants require far more management.
Billing is easier per tenant but harder if you have many.
Also, they don't scale.
You might end up with multiple tenants in multiple subscriptions.

Thank you.. atleast two to 3 applications per business unit and there are around 500 business units and per application there would be approximately 100+ users per application.. .. Please share the limitation as we are trying to build a design for it..
